# Ты придёшь скоро, и я тогда буду рад(,) или ты придёшь не скоро?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Ты придёшь скоро, и я тогда буду рад(,) или ты придёшь не скоро?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Ты придёшь скоро, и я тогда буду рад, или ты придёшь не скоро?***

Грамматическую основу *я буду рад* нужно отделить от другой — *ты придешь*.

Comment: Это как вставка. *Ты придёшь скоро — и я тогда буду рад — или ты придёшь не скоро?*

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр _Ты придешь скоро — и я тогда буду рад, — или ты придешь ре скоро. Запятая ставится по структуре, без нее никак, отделяет одну от другой. Запятая в любом случае ставится.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Пробел после упомянания не убрал. В общем, вот.